# how to I find the distance from a function to an orthonormal basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I've gotten this assignment:

Let $M = span(e^{-2πit}, 1, e^{2πit})$ in $L^2[0,1]$. Compute the orthogonal projection of $f(t) = t^2$ to M and compute the distance between f and M.

I've already confirmed that M is an orthonormal basis and I've computed the projection, but I don't know how to compute the distance between f and M.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pythagoras, $(f - P_M(f)) \perp P_M(f)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer so it's basicly taking the inner product of those two?

Comment: The inner product of those two is $0$. You want the length of $f - P_M(f)$.